# How to inquire about adverse events of aspirin in the open FDA？

Tags: openfda, drugs

I want to check the adverse events of aspirin drugs in the open fda data within the specified date
I have tried many times and it keeps getting an error display
Where did I go wrong ？ How can I query correctly？
I try to:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc:"aspirin+Antipyretic and analgesic+drug"&limit=1

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc:"Antipyretic+analgesic+drug"&limit=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL you are using has quotation marks (") which are enforcing an exact match.

Please try this URL

https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc:aspirin%20Antipyretic%20analgesic%20drug&limit=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that searches across the entire dataset: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.substance_name.exact:%22ASPIRIN%22

You can narrow down further by specifying a date range such as: [https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.substance_name.exact:%22ASPIRIN%22+AND+receivedate:[2020-01-01+TO+2020-01-31]](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.substance_name.exact:%22ASPIRIN%22%20AND%20receivedate:%5B2020-01-01%20TO%202020-01-31%5D)

Comment: what is the difference between using brand_name vs substance_name: ASPIRIN? In JSON, I don't find any difference.